# SML: Comparing every element of two lists without storing state info?

Tags: list, sml, smlnj

I have an SML assignment, and the general idea is that I shouldn't store state info, should not used built in library functions, etc and just solve in a functional way. Not sure how to do it:

The question requires comparing every element of two lists together:

### input

list1: [(3,3,5),(5,4,7),(2,3,4)];
list2: [3, 6];

### output

newList: [(3,3,5), (2,3,5)]

Essentially, when the second element in list1's tuple arg matches an item in list 2, then I should add the list1 item to the new output list.

The way I went about implementing it:

```
fun thing(x, y) = 
   if null x then []
   else if #2 (hd x) = (hd y) then hd x @ thing(tl x, y)
   else thing(tl x, y);
```

Obviously the issue with this is that I lose state information: how would you match every element in list1 against every element in list2?

Answer (score 1):

> when the second element in list1's tuple arg matches an item in list 2,
> then I should add the list1 item to the new output list.
>
> ```
> fun thing(x, y) = 
>   if null x then []
>   else if #2 (hd x) = (hd y) then hd x @ thing(tl x, y)
>   else thing(tl x, y);
> ```

Instead of `if null x then ...`, `hd x` and `tl x`, use pattern matching:

```
fun thing ([], _) = ...
  | thing ((x,y,z)::haystack, needles) = ...
```

To find out if `y` is a member of `needles`, build a membership function:

```
fun elem (p, []) = false
  | elem (p, q::qs) = p = q orelse elem (p, qs)
```

Check if `elem (y, needles)` to determine whether to include `(x,y,z)` as part of your result.

Apply `thing` recursively to `haystack` and `needles`.

Compose the recursive result using the `::` (cons) operator rather than `@` (append).

---

Here's how one could solve this exercise with library functions:

```
fun curry f x y = f (x, y)
fun thing (haystack, needles) =
    List.filter (fn (x,y,z) =>
      List.exists (curry op= y) needles) haystack
```